# SQL Developer - Updating/Inserting sum of column from different table based on distinct ID

Tags: sql, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

**Amateur SQL writer here having a problem with building out table based on values from an existing one.**

The MASTER table logs a record with an ID every time a service is used. ID remains the same per user, but will repeat to track relevant information during that usage. Table holds about 2m records and 20k DISTINCT IDs.

*Example -
*USER ID*  |  Used_Amount

USER_1998  | 9GB,
USER_1999  | 4GB,
USER_1999  | 1GB,
USER_1999  |0.5 GB*

Would like for the new table is create column that SUMS the usage and organizes based on DISTINCT ID.

- Goal -
  ID       .   TOTAL USAGE
  USER_1998 - 9GB
  USER_1999 - 5.5GB

Code below is my attempt...

```
UPDATE ml_draft  
SET true_usage = (  
SELECT SUM(true_usage)  
FROM table2 t2  
INNER JOIN ml_draft ON  
ml_draft.subscription_id = t2.subscription_id);
```

Let me know if there are any additional details to add. Errors vary

Answer (score 0):

You want a *correlated* subquery.  So, there is no need to use `JOIN` in the subquery:

```
UPDATE ml_draft d
    SET true_usage = (SELECT SUM(t2.true_usage)  
                      FROM table2 t2  
                      WHERE d.subscription_id = t2.subscription_id
                     );
```

For performance, you want an index on `table2(subscription_id, true_usage)`.

Comment: I believe this is working, however SQL keeps timing out...currently looking into connection pooling.   Error at Command Line : 97 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: Closed Connection  Also, not sure if this changes anything but there is no true_usage column in the MASTER table. Only the amount used during that particular session. I shouldn't of put SUM(true_usage) into the table, rather SUM(used_amount) to get the true_usage I'm looking for